# Use Zapier Webhooks with Doorbird D202 http(s) Calls Function

Tags: home-automation, doorbell

Inside the Doorbird Administration Settings there is a section called "https(s) Calls". Is this where you should enter a Zapier Webhook URL to listen for events such as Doorbell?

Here is the config inside the Doorbird Admin Section:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on SO or SuperUser. It's not DIY/Home-Improvement.

Comment: what does the instruction manual say? ..

Comment: probably yes ... a `hook` in computer language is a place for intercepting software signals, such as event messages

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a programming issue not home improvement. Funny now 3 statements VTC or move but no one else actually voted. Is something going on with the system all the old posts I have looked at today appear to be dated sep 7